# angular.js $http.post not working - no error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to submit a new comment using $http. You might have guessed it from the title: it's not working. I tried the shore version and the long version, both fail. No console error.

This is my code:

```
$scope.comment = {};
$scope.comment["comment"] = message; // message defined somewhere else

$http.post('/api/items/'+$scope.item.id+'/comments', $scope.comment)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         // this isn't happening:
         console.debug("saved comment", $scope.comment);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         // this isn't happening:
         console.debug("saved comment", $scope.comment);
    })
}
```

Anyone got any idea on how to make this work? Thanks!

UPDATE:

I'm doing it as a Jquery ajax call now, which is working fine. It'd be nice to get it to work with angular though. This is my JQuery code however:

```
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: '/api/items/'+$scope.item.id+'/comments',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify($scope.comment),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json"
            });

            request.done(function(msg) {
                console.debug("saved comment", $scope.comment);
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
```

If anyone has any ideas how to angularify this please tell me, would be nice to do it the proper way....

Comment: Are you sure these lines of code are executed?

Comment: yes. console.debug after setting the comment logs the correct data. However $http.post doesn't seem to work.

Comment: posting to this url works, say from fiddler? and assuming idea with id 5 exists posting to this url works '/api/ideas/5/comments' ?

Comment: I checked in Charles Proxt and there doesn't seem to be a POST request happening... so I assume it's a problem with the frontend, not the backend?

Comment: Have you been able to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: hybrid with ajax or jquery seems to be the only way left since the angular still full of bug and lack of documentation ( compare to jquery ajax )

Comment: Same error for me. $http.post fails silently, no error. Have tried about 10 different people's suggested syntax.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Neither the success or fail callbacks are being called. I believe it's related to the file I am posting.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried specifically setting the Content-Type before making the request?

I had the same issue and setting Content-Type fixes it.

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help you. I had similiar problem with get call : [AngularJS $http not firing get call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701503/angularjs-http-not-firing-get-call)

I solved it with solution, found here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2794#issuecomment-18807158, so I wraped my call function with $scope.$apply.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
                console.log('Klic na ID ' + data.context.id);
                $scope.commonController.getData('orgunit/' + data.context.id + '?jsonDepth=3')
                    .success(function(workpositionData,status,headers,config) {
                        console.log('Klic na ID ' + data.context.id + ' OK');
                        $scope.workPositions = workpositionData.workPositions;
                    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config) {
                        commonController.error('Pri branju delovnih mest je prišlo do napake: '+data.description);
                    });
            });
```

Comment: This makes sense. The linked page mentions that $http creates a promise, and promises are only resolved within the $digest cycle.
@Dine, where does your code run? If it runs within a `setTimeout` or within a jQuery/DOM event listener function, then that's your problem. You need to call $scope.$apply(), which in turn triggers the $digest cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you just forgot some cruel ")"
try

```
$http.post('/api/ideas/'+$scope.item.id+'/comments', $scope.comment)
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // this isn't happening:
     console.debug("saved comment", $scope.comment);
   })  //<-- damn ")"
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // this isn't happening:
     console.debug("saved comment", $scope.comment);
   }) //<--- damn ")"
 }
```

I did not test it yet, but I bet, this is the error
regards

Comment: This is a very valid point, unfortunately this is not the problem as it is only a typo which slipped into stackoverflow but is actually correct in my app (I corrected it in stackoverflow now). Would most likely have caused am error in the console. So yeah - still not working...

Comment: Please Provide Us a Plunker .. where people can do something to Make it Working

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular 1.1.4+ check this thread https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2431.

Basically if you are calling $http outside of Angular context you need to wrap $http callback in $scope.$apply. For more details look into https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2794#issuecomment-18807158

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem. The way I solved it was to use .then() 
and registering the success and error callbacks as arguments. In your case:

```
$http.post('/api/items/'+$scope.item.id+'/comments', $scope.comment)
  .then(
    // success callback
    function(response) {
      console.debug("success - saved comment", $scope.comment);
    },
    // error callback
    function(response) {
      console.debug("error - saved comment", $scope.comment);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the controller with the $http object. Same goes for the other Angular services you wish to use.

E.g.:

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {
  // controller code
}
```

Comment: I did inject the $http object. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

**Angular js post call:**

```
$http({
        url:'/api/ideas/'+$scope.item.id+'/comments', $scope.comment,
        method : 'POST'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    });
```

**Rest Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping
    (value = "/api/ideas/{item_id}/comments/{comment}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void updateComments(@PathVariable String item_id,@PathVariable String comment) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//set arg
var arg = { name: $scope.name,
           tel: $scope.tel} 
// config 
var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/pServices/sellers/addNew',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data: arg
            }
//POST data to server 
$http(req).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
                if(data['data']['status'])
                 console.log('success') ;

            }, function(data, status, headers, config){
                 console.log(data['data']['message']) 
            });
```

Comment: it would be better if you can add some explanation about your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
angular.module('RestService', [

]).factory('$RestService', [
    '$http', 'ApiUrl',
    function ($http, ApiUrl) {
        return {          
            Functioname: function (request) {
                var Requesturl = ApiUrl + "/Functionname";//www.test.com/getuserdata
                return this.Post(Requesturl, request);//request :parameter which you want to pass in post request
            },
            Post: function (ResultUrl, RequestParameterData) {
                var PostResponse = $http({
                    url: ResultUrl,
                    method: "POST",
                    dataType: "",
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
                    data: RequestParameterData
                });
                return PostResponse;
            },
            Get: function (ResultUrl, RequestParameterData) {
                var PostResponse = $http({
                    url: ResultUrl,
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "",
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
                    data: RequestParameterData
                });
                return PostResponse;
            }

        };
    }


]);
```