# $http not working. No errors are returned in console

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-http

I'm making a mobile app and I have a controller that handles user login. It makes a http call (currently to localhost) to check if the user is valid. For some reason it won't fire off the $http call and the console says nothing about it failing. I'm new to AngularJS and I've probably made a beginner mistake in my code. I'm using AngularJS with Ionic Framework.

This is my LoginController:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', 'User', '$window', '$http', '$templateCache', function($scope, $ionicPopup, User, $window, $http, $templateCache){
    $scope.authUser = function(){
        console.log('authUser initialized');
        var email = document.getElementById('User_email');
        var password = document.getElementById('User_password');
        console.log('email=' + email.value);
        console.log('password=' + password.value);

        console.log('logging in...');
        if(email.value == '' || password.value == ''){
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Failed to login',
                template: 'Both fields need to be filled.'
            });
            alertPopup.then(function(res){
                console.log('Both fields need to be filled.');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Contacting API server...');
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://api.tb.local/api.php',
                    data: { 'action': 'user/auth', 'email': email.value, 'password': password.value },
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    cache: $templateCache
                }).
                success(function(response){
                    console.log('Response success');
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.valid){
                        console.log('Login success. Redirecting to welcome page...');
                        $window.location.href = '#/welcome';
                    } else {
                        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: 'Failed to login',
                            template: 'Wrong credentials. Please try again.'
                        });
                        alertPopup.then(function(res){
                            console.log('Wrong credentials. Please try again.');
                        });
                    }
                }).
                error(function(response){
                    var requestFailDialog = $ionicPopup({
                        title: 'Internal Error',
                        template: 'The server encountered an unknown error.'
                    });
                    requestFailDialog.then(function(res){
                        console.log('Internal Error: ' + response);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

The last thing I get in my console is `Contacting API server...`.

I tested my API manually and it returns a json `{ "valid": true }` just like it should.

Comment: Why do you have the whole $http call inside $scope.$apply({}) ? Try removing that.

Comment: @TomErikStøwer I took $scope.$apply({}) from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299362/angular-js-http-post-not-working-no-error as I thought my issue was because of that. But with or without it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: in console, 'Response success' is printing ?

Comment: @NitishKumar Nope. As I said in my question, the last thing I get in my console is Contacting API server which is right before the $http call. The whole $http doesn't get fired.

Comment: remove cache from $http and try

Comment: @NitishKumar surprisingly it started working when I removed the cache from it. Thank you. But how could have the cache prevented it from working? Also could you post it as an answer so I can mark it :)

Comment: cache is a boolean config variable. Did you have a boolean value in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Remove `cache: $templateCache` from $http request.