# Passing status code from Laravel not received by Angular http

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I'm building a front end Angular App, and a separate Laravel 5.1 API. I'm testing registration validation by POSTing duplicate e-mail addresses.

When it throws an error with status code,

`return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);`

my Angular `$http` method doesn't receive the response at all, and therefore `success` NOR `error` methods are called on the Angular response.

However, if I remove the status code `422` from `JsonResponse`:

```
return new JsonResponse($errors);
```

I can receive the response into Angular.

I find this odd because using the status code `422` still returns a response from the Network tab, but it's not received by Angular:

**422 (Unprocessable Entity)**

**Response: email : ["The email has already been taken."]**

I'd like to pass along the status code from Laravel because I want a **non 200** to trigger the Angular `$http .error` response.

*Code snippets:*

**Angular**:

```
signup: function(params) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + ver + '/auth/register',
        data: params,
        cache: true
    });
}

Auth.signup(scope.user).success(function(res){
     console.log(res);
}).error(function(err) {
    alertify.error('There was an error with your login credentials. Please try again');
});
```

**Laravel**:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors)
{
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }
```

---

EDIT: I was also thinking it may be an issue with Angular `error` not being triggered by the `422` code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299362/angular-js-http-post-not-working-no-error) says to add at the top but this did not fix the issue

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Answer (score 1):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Try using `then` instead:

```
Auth.signup(scope.user).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}, function(err) {
    alertify.error('There was an error with your login credentials. Please try again');
});
```

Comment: Hmm odd, that seems to work. Not sure why deprecation would cause breaks though

Comment: @Growler are you using an $http interceptor? if so see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22425383/3574819